# UnexpectedRollbackException in Spring with AOP @AfterReturning

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

I have set up a logging for every save operation using Spring AOP where I marked with `@Transactional`. The problem is when my save method has throw an exception and mark the transaction with rollback only, but the logging operation using AOP doesnt know. That why it lead to:

> 'Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only'.

How to overcome this kind of situation?

My save method:

```
@Transactional
public void create(SecModuleRequest secModuleRequest) {
  SecModule secModule = secModuleRepository.save(pData); // throw data integrity exception
}
```

My logging method:

```
@Transactional
@AfterReturning(value = "execution(public * save(..)) && this(org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository)", returning = "responseEntity")
public void onSaveExecuted(JoinPoint pjp, Object responseEntity) {
    try {            
        ...            
        insertAuditLog(jsonStr, entityActionLog.getQueryClauseExt());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int insertAuditLog(String auditContent, String queryRowId) {
    String sql = " Insert into LOG (LOG_ID,LOG_DATETIME, LOG_CONTENT) " +
            "           values (LOG_SEQ.NEXTVAL, SYSDATE, ?) ";
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter(1, auditContent);        
    int resultInsert = query.executeUpdate();
    return resultInsert;
}
```

Comment: Have you try to add method annotated with `@AfterThrowing` to catch exception from save method

Comment: It cant catch an exception cause the save method doesnt throw any exception until it hit the last statement of transactional method (create method). That why it will jump to my logging method first and make the UnexpectedRollbackException happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think sequence of method calls here are as follows

Method `create()` starts a transaction and calls the method `secModuleRepository.save(pData)`.

Assuming the `secModuleRepository.save(pData)` has the default transaction propogation [`REQUIRED`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#propagation--) , it takes part in the transaction which got started with method `create()`.

The `save()` returns without any exception and gets adviced by the `@AfterReturning` advice method `onSaveExecuted()`.

This transaction would result in a `DataIntegrityViolationException` when the transaction gets committed. This happens at the end of that transaction , which is when the control exits the method `create()`.

To log the `save()` method calls on all the cases, the advice type should be either `@After` or `@Around` and the log call should not be part of the transaction which could rollback at commit.

Following code uses a `TransactionTemplate` to start a new transaction and insert the log. The idea is to have a new transaction to log and the example code given reuses the code shared with the question can be improved per requirement.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TxnAspect {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    // single TransactionTemplate shared amongst all methods in this instance
    private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    // use constructor-injection to supply the PlatformTransactionManager
    public TxnAspect(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    }

    @Around(value = "execution(public * save(..)) && this(org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository)")
    public Object onSaveExecuted(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object responseEntity = null;
        try {
            responseEntity = pjp.proceed();
        } finally {
            //gather the details and log
            executeInNewTxn("log1","log2");
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }

    public Object executeInNewTxn(String str1, String str2) {
        transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.value());
        return transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
            // the code in this method executes in a transactional context
            public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                return insertAuditLog(str1, str2);
            }
        });
    }

    public int insertAuditLog(String auditContent, String queryRowId) {
        String sql = " Insert into LOG (LOG_ID,LOG_DATETIME, LOG_CONTENT) "
                + "           values (100, SYSDATE, ?) ";
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter(1, auditContent);
        int resultInsert = query.executeUpdate();
        return resultInsert;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried to create a new transaction by using @Transactional(Propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) but it still fallback using the same transaction. But switching to TransactionTemplate, It work like a charm now. Many thanks.

Comment: If your question is answered , could you please upvote (up arrow) if you found this useful and mark it as the answer (tick mark) ?

Comment: I've already upvoted for your answered but seem like my reputation is less than 15 so it recored but not displayed as scored. Thanks for your answer, I found it very useful.